# Conditional JSON Formating a choice column based on the value of another column

Tags: json, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to select a choice on a column if a specific value is on another column.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$Location],'Hawaii') != -1,'Deliver',''))"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data/column type of "Location" column? Can add a screenshot with sample list data to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below JSON in [column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) option for your column:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$Location]), toLowerCase('Hawaii')) != -1, 'Deliver', @currentField)"
    }
}
```

**Note**: JSON formatting does not set the actual column value, it only customizes the display of column to show the value in list view.